# Does conflicts happen among gods with their duties?

Tags: gods

Hinduism has numerous gods. So how do different gods make similar decisions for all activities? For example, one god decides today is a rainy day and another one decides today is a sunny day. Then they have conflict among them, so this means that there will be greater probability of conflicts amongst Hindu gods.

Comment: The gods don't decide such things. They merely perform their duty according to schedule. And they don't have much say on the weather.

Comment: Plus each god has a separate duty, so there is no clash of opinion. :)

Comment: Good question! There are plenty of incidents in Hindu Scriptures where the Devas and Asuras have conflicts. However it must be said that Devas cannot be equated with God of other religions. While Devas have certain Godly qualities, Devas are not the God. According to Hinduism, God is One. Ekam Evadvithiyam Brahma. (God is One without a second). Thus all the Devas and all of creation goes by the Will of the Omniscient Illuminating One Reality called Parabrahma AKA God. All the best.

Comment: @Sai Nicely phrased.

Comment: @Surya If god is one then who is that god?

Answer (score 2):

The gods, devas, and the elements follow the will of Isvara, they do not make independent decisions. In his commentary to *Brahma Sutras* verse 2.3.13, Sankara says:

> Brahman is described in the Srutis as the creator of everything. Again we find in them texts like "From Akasa is produced air" (Tai. 2.1) which declare that certain elements produce certain effects independently. So the opponent holds that there is a contradiction in the Sruti texts. Why? On account of the indicatory marks. "He who inhabits the earth...and controls the earth from within" etc. (Br. 3.7.3) shows that the Supreme Lord is the sole ruler, and denies all independence to the elements. Again, "That fire thought,...that water thought" (Ch. 6.2.3-4) shows that after reflection these elements produced the effects. This reflection is impossible for inert elements and so we are to understand that the Lord residing within these elements thought and produced the effects. Therefore the elements become causes only through the agency of the Lord, who abides within them. Hence there is no contradiction between the two texts cited in the beginning.

In the *Pancadasi* (VI.107) of Vidyaranya Swami it says (Swami Swahananda translator):

> The Sruti declares that Nature functions in fear of Isvara. He is the ruler though unattached...(Vide Taittiriya Up. 2.8.1, Katha Up. 2.3.3, Nrsimhatapaniya Up. 2...)

SO whether it is the devas or the elements, it is the Lord within them whose will is done and acting through them as agents of the Lord's will.